# What are the HSK chengyu (idioms)?

Tags: chengyu, hsk

I've been going through the HSK lists with awk, so I now feel like I can answer...

**Question**: What are the HSK chengyu (idioms)?

My answer is below.

To my knowledge, there's no HSK5 idioms, except possibly [讨价还价](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%AE%A8%E4%BB%B7%E8%BF%98%E4%BB%B7) (to haggle over price), but I don't think that counts.  This is not to say there's no requirement to learn idioms for HSK5, but that it's not on [the official list](http://www.chinesetest.cn/userfiles/file/HSK/HSK-2012.xls).

There's now answers for the [HSK2.0](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/36415/8099) and [HSK3.0](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/51376/8099).  Almost all HSK3.0 chengyu (all but the first 8 listed) are for level 7+.

Comment: [This YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCiFQ79SmeA) gives example sentences for a lot of them.

Comment: I think idioms成语 entries: 377，Can you check it again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HSK6 idioms (from [vocab list](http://www.chinesetest.cn/userfiles/file/HSK/HSK-2012.xls)).  English definitions from [CC-CEDICT](https://cc-cedict.org/editor/editor.php).

1. > **一丝不苟** (yīsībùgǒu)
   > not one thread loose (idiom); strictly according to the rules
   > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%80%E4%B8%9D%E4%B8%8D%E8%8B%9F); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E4%B8%80%E4%B8%9D%E4%B8%8D%E8%8B%9F); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E4%B8%80%E4%B8%9D%E4%B8%8D%E8%8B%9F)</sub>
2. > **一举两得** (yījǔliǎngdé)
   > one move, two gains (idiom); two birds with one stone
   > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%80%E4%B8%BE%E4%B8%A4%E5%BE%97); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E4%B8%80%E4%B8%BE%E4%B8%A4%E5%BE%97); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E4%B8%80%E4%B8%BE%E4%B8%A4%E5%BE%97)</sub>
3. > **一如既往** (yīrújìwǎng)
   > just as in the past (idiom); as before
   > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%80%E5%A6%82%E6%97%A2%E5%BE%80); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E4%B8%80%E5%A6%82%E6%97%A2%E5%BE%80); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E4%B8%80%E5%A6%82%E6%97%A2%E5%BE%80)</sub>
4. > **一帆风顺** (yīfānfēngshùn)
   > propitious wind throughout the journey (idiom)
   > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%80%E5%B8%86%E9%A3%8E%E9%A1%BA/72491); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E4%B8%80%E5%B8%86%E9%A3%8E%E9%A1%BA); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E4%B8%80%E5%B8%86%E9%A3%8E%E9%A1%BA)</sub>
5. > **一目了然** (yīmùliǎorán)
   > obvious at a glance (idiom)
   > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%80%E7%9B%AE%E4%BA%86%E7%84%B6); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E4%B8%80%E7%9B%AE%E4%BA%86%E7%84%B6); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E4%B8%80%E7%9B%AE%E4%BA%86%E7%84%B6)</sub>
6. > **不可思议** (bùkěsīyì)
   > inconceivable (idiom); unimaginable
   > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%8D%E5%8F%AF%E6%80%9D%E8%AE%AE/2401?fr=aladdin); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E4%B8%8D%E5%8F%AF%E6%80%9D%E8%AE%AE); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E4%B8%8D%E5%8F%AF%E6%80%9D%E8%AE%AE)</sub>
7. > **不屑一顾** (bùxièyīgù)
   > to disdain as beneath contempt (idiom)
   > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%8D%E5%B1%91%E4%B8%80%E9%A1%BE); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E4%B8%8D%E5%B1%91%E4%B8%80%E9%A1%BE); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E4%B8%8D%E5%B1%91%E4%B8%80%E9%A1%BE)</sub>
8. > **不择手段** (bùzéshǒuduàn)
   > by fair means or foul
   > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%8D%E6%8B%A9%E6%89%8B%E6%AE%B5); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E4%B8%8D%E6%8B%A9%E6%89%8B%E6%AE%B5); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E4%B8%8D%E6%8B%A9%E6%89%8B%E6%AE%B5)</sub>
9. > **不相上下** (bùxiāngshàngxià)
   > equally matched
   > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%8D%E7%9B%B8%E4%B8%8A%E4%B8%8B); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E4%B8%8D%E7%9B%B8%E4%B8%8A%E4%B8%8B); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E4%B8%8D%E7%9B%B8%E4%B8%8A%E4%B8%8B)</sub>
10. > **不言而喻** (bùyánéryù)
    > it goes without saying
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%8D%E8%A8%80%E8%80%8C%E5%96%BB); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E4%B8%8D%E8%A8%80%E8%80%8C%E5%96%BB); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E4%B8%8D%E8%A8%80%E8%80%8C%E5%96%BB)</sub>
11. > **与日俱增** (yǔrìjùzēng)
    > to increase steadily
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%8E%E6%97%A5%E4%BF%B1%E5%A2%9E); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E4%B8%8E%E6%97%A5%E4%BF%B1%E5%A2%9E); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E4%B8%8E%E6%97%A5%E4%BF%B1%E5%A2%9E)</sub>
12. > **东张西望** (dōngzhāngxīwàng)
    > to look in all directions (idiom)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%9C%E5%BC%A0%E8%A5%BF%E6%9C%9B); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E4%B8%9C%E5%BC%A0%E8%A5%BF%E6%9C%9B); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E4%B8%9C%E5%BC%A0%E8%A5%BF%E6%9C%9B)</sub>
13. > **丢三落四** (diūsānlàsì)
    > forgetful
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%A2%E4%B8%89%E8%90%BD%E5%9B%9B/6758482); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E4%B8%A2%E4%B8%89%E8%90%BD%E5%9B%9B); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E4%B8%A2%E4%B8%89%E8%90%BD%E5%9B%9B)</sub>
14. > **举世瞩目** (jǔshìzhǔmù)
    > to receive worldwide attention
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%BE%E4%B8%96%E7%9E%A9%E7%9B%AE); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E4%B8%BE%E4%B8%96%E7%9E%A9%E7%9B%AE); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E4%B8%BE%E4%B8%96%E7%9E%A9%E7%9B%AE)</sub>
15. > **举足轻重** (jǔzúqīngzhòng)
    > to play a critical role (idiom)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%BE%E8%B6%B3%E8%BD%BB%E9%87%8D); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E4%B8%BE%E8%B6%B3%E8%BD%BB%E9%87%8D); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E4%B8%BE%E8%B6%B3%E8%BD%BB%E9%87%8D)</sub>
16. > **争先恐后** (zhēngxiānkǒnghòu)
    > striving to be first and fearing to be last (idiom); outdoing one another
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%BA%89%E5%85%88%E6%81%90%E5%90%8E/1663456); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E4%BA%89%E5%85%88%E6%81%90%E5%90%8E); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E4%BA%89%E5%85%88%E6%81%90%E5%90%8E)</sub>
17. > **任重道远** (rènzhòngdàoyuǎn)
    > a heavy load and a long road
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%BB%BB%E9%87%8D%E9%81%93%E8%BF%9C); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E4%BB%BB%E9%87%8D%E9%81%93%E8%BF%9C); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E4%BB%BB%E9%87%8D%E9%81%93%E8%BF%9C)</sub>
18. > **众所周知** (zhòngsuǒzhōuzhī)
    > as everyone knows (idiom)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%BC%97%E6%89%80%E5%91%A8%E7%9F%A5); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E4%BC%97%E6%89%80%E5%91%A8%E7%9F%A5); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E4%BC%97%E6%89%80%E5%91%A8%E7%9F%A5)</sub>
19. > **优胜劣汰** (yōushèngliètài)
    > survival of the fittest (idiom)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%BC%98%E8%83%9C%E5%8A%A3%E6%B1%B0); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E4%BC%98%E8%83%9C%E5%8A%A3%E6%B1%B0); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E4%BC%98%E8%83%9C%E5%8A%A3%E6%B1%B0)</sub>
20. > **侃侃而谈** (kǎnkǎnértán)
    > to speak frankly with assurance
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%BE%83%E4%BE%83%E8%80%8C%E8%B0%88); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E4%BE%83%E4%BE%83%E8%80%8C%E8%B0%88); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E4%BE%83%E4%BE%83%E8%80%8C%E8%B0%88)</sub>
21. > **供不应求** (gōngbùyìngqiú)
    > supply does not meet demand
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%BE%9B%E4%B8%8D%E5%BA%94%E6%B1%82); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E4%BE%9B%E4%B8%8D%E5%BA%94%E6%B1%82); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E4%BE%9B%E4%B8%8D%E5%BA%94%E6%B1%82)</sub>
22. > **兢兢业业** (jīngjīngyèyè)
    > cautious and conscientious
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%85%A2%E5%85%A2%E4%B8%9A%E4%B8%9A); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%85%A2%E5%85%A2%E4%B8%9A%E4%B8%9A); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E5%85%A2%E5%85%A2%E4%B8%9A%E4%B8%9A)</sub>
23. > **全力以赴** (quánlìyǐfù)
    > to do at all costs
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%85%A8%E5%8A%9B%E4%BB%A5%E8%B5%B4); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%85%A8%E5%8A%9B%E4%BB%A5%E8%B5%B4); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E5%85%A8%E5%8A%9B%E4%BB%A5%E8%B5%B4)</sub>
24. > **兴致勃勃** (xìngzhìbóbó)
    > to become exhilarated (idiom); in high spirits
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%85%B4%E8%87%B4%E5%8B%83%E5%8B%83); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%85%B4%E8%87%B4%E5%8B%83%E5%8B%83); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E5%85%B4%E8%87%B4%E5%8B%83%E5%8B%83)</sub>
25. > **兴高采烈** (xìnggāocǎiliè)
    > happy and excited (idiom)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%85%B4%E9%AB%98%E9%87%87%E7%83%88); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%85%B4%E9%AB%98%E9%87%87%E7%83%88); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E5%85%B4%E9%AB%98%E9%87%87%E7%83%88)</sub>
26. > **再接再厉** (zàijiēzàilì)
    > to continue the struggle (idiom); to persist
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%86%8D%E6%8E%A5%E5%86%8D%E5%8E%89); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%86%8D%E6%8E%A5%E5%86%8D%E5%8E%89); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E5%86%8D%E6%8E%A5%E5%86%8D%E5%8E%89)</sub>
27. > **刻不容缓** (kèbùrónghuǎn)
    > to brook no delay
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%88%BB%E4%B8%8D%E5%AE%B9%E7%BC%93/1987); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%88%BB%E4%B8%8D%E5%AE%B9%E7%BC%93); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E5%88%BB%E4%B8%8D%E5%AE%B9%E7%BC%93)</sub>
28. > **力所能及** (lìsuǒnéngjí)
    > as far as one's capabilities extend (idiom); to the best of one's ability
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%8A%9B%E6%89%80%E8%83%BD%E5%8F%8A); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%8A%9B%E6%89%80%E8%83%BD%E5%8F%8A); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E5%8A%9B%E6%89%80%E8%83%BD%E5%8F%8A)</sub>
29. > **千方百计** (qiānfāngbǎijì)
    > lit. thousand ways, a hundred plans (idiom); by every possible means
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%8D%83%E6%96%B9%E7%99%BE%E8%AE%A1/10285585); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%8D%83%E6%96%B9%E7%99%BE%E8%AE%A1); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E5%8D%83%E6%96%B9%E7%99%BE%E8%AE%A1)</sub>
30. > **半途而废** (bàntú'érfèi)
    > to give up halfway (idiom); leave sth unfinished
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%8D%8A%E9%80%94%E8%80%8C%E5%BA%9F/81912); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%8D%8A%E9%80%94%E8%80%8C%E5%BA%9F); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E5%8D%8A%E9%80%94%E8%80%8C%E5%BA%9F)</sub>
31. > **南辕北辙** (nányuánběizhé)
    > to act in a way that defeats one's purpose (idiom)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%8D%97%E8%BE%95%E5%8C%97%E8%BE%99); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%8D%97%E8%BE%95%E5%8C%97%E8%BE%99); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E5%8D%97%E8%BE%95%E5%8C%97%E8%BE%99)</sub>
32. > **博大精深** (bódàjīngshēn)
    > wide-ranging and profound
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%8D%9A%E5%A4%A7%E7%B2%BE%E6%B7%B1); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%8D%9A%E5%A4%A7%E7%B2%BE%E6%B7%B1); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E5%8D%9A%E5%A4%A7%E7%B2%BE%E6%B7%B1)</sub>
33. > **各抒己见** (gèshūjǐjiàn)
    > everyone gives their own view
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%90%84%E6%8A%92%E5%B7%B1%E8%A7%81); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%90%84%E6%8A%92%E5%B7%B1%E8%A7%81); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E5%90%84%E6%8A%92%E5%B7%B1%E8%A7%81)</sub>
34. > **名副其实** (míngfùqíshí)
    > not just in name only, but also in reality (idiom)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%90%8D%E5%89%AF%E5%85%B6%E5%AE%9E); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%90%8D%E5%89%AF%E5%85%B6%E5%AE%9E); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E5%90%8D%E5%89%AF%E5%85%B6%E5%AE%9E)</sub>
35. > **后顾之忧** (hòugùzhīyōu)
    > fears of trouble in the rear (idiom); family worries (obstructing freedom of action)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%90%8E%E9%A1%BE%E4%B9%8B%E5%BF%A7); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%90%8E%E9%A1%BE%E4%B9%8B%E5%BF%A7); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E5%90%8E%E9%A1%BE%E4%B9%8B%E5%BF%A7)</sub>
36. > **吞吞吐吐** (tūntūntǔtǔ)
    > to hum and haw (idiom); to mumble as if hiding sth
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%90%9E%E5%90%9E%E5%90%90%E5%90%90); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%90%9E%E5%90%9E%E5%90%90%E5%90%90); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E5%90%9E%E5%90%9E%E5%90%90%E5%90%90)</sub>
37. > **喜闻乐见** (xǐwénlèjiàn)
    > to love to hear and see (idiom)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%96%9C%E9%97%BB%E4%B9%90%E8%A7%81/3717152); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%96%9C%E9%97%BB%E4%B9%90%E8%A7%81); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E5%96%9C%E9%97%BB%E4%B9%90%E8%A7%81)</sub>
38. > **天伦之乐** (tiānlúnzhīlè)
    > family love and joy
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%A4%A9%E4%BC%A6%E4%B9%8B%E4%B9%90); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%A4%A9%E4%BC%A6%E4%B9%8B%E4%B9%90); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E5%A4%A9%E4%BC%A6%E4%B9%8B%E4%B9%90)</sub>
39. > **实事求是** (shíshìqiúshì)
    > to seek truth from facts (idiom)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%AE%9E%E4%BA%8B%E6%B1%82%E6%98%AF); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%AE%9E%E4%BA%8B%E6%B1%82%E6%98%AF); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E5%AE%9E%E4%BA%8B%E6%B1%82%E6%98%AF)</sub>
40. > **家喻户晓** (jiāyùhùxiǎo)
    > understood by everyone (idiom); well known
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%AE%B6%E5%96%BB%E6%88%B7%E6%99%93); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%AE%B6%E5%96%BB%E6%88%B7%E6%99%93); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E5%AE%B6%E5%96%BB%E6%88%B7%E6%99%93)</sub>
41. > **小心翼翼** (xiǎoxīnyìyì)
    > cautious and solemn (idiom); very carefully
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%B0%8F%E5%BF%83%E7%BF%BC%E7%BF%BC); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%B0%8F%E5%BF%83%E7%BF%BC%E7%BF%BC); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E5%B0%8F%E5%BF%83%E7%BF%BC%E7%BF%BC)</sub>
42. > **层出不穷** (céngchūbùqióng)
    > more and more emerge
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%B1%82%E5%87%BA%E4%B8%8D%E7%A9%B7); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%B1%82%E5%87%BA%E4%B8%8D%E7%A9%B7); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E5%B1%82%E5%87%BA%E4%B8%8D%E7%A9%B7)</sub>
43. > **岂有此理** (qǐyǒucǐlǐ)
    > how can this be so? (idiom); preposterous
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%B2%82%E6%9C%89%E6%AD%A4%E7%90%86); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%B2%82%E6%9C%89%E6%AD%A4%E7%90%86); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E5%B2%82%E6%9C%89%E6%AD%A4%E7%90%86)</sub>
44. > **川流不息** (chuānliúbùxī)
    > the stream flows without stopping (idiom); unending flow
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%B7%9D%E6%B5%81%E4%B8%8D%E6%81%AF/4829); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%B7%9D%E6%B5%81%E4%B8%8D%E6%81%AF); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E5%B7%9D%E6%B5%81%E4%B8%8D%E6%81%AF)</sub>
45. > **废寝忘食** (fèiqǐnwàngshí)
    > to neglect sleep and forget about food (idiom)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%BA%9F%E5%AF%9D%E5%BF%98%E9%A3%9F); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%BA%9F%E5%AF%9D%E5%BF%98%E9%A3%9F); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E5%BA%9F%E5%AF%9D%E5%BF%98%E9%A3%9F)</sub>
46. > **归根到底** (guīgēndàodǐ)
    > after all
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%BD%92%E6%A0%B9%E5%88%B0%E5%BA%95); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%BD%92%E6%A0%B9%E5%88%B0%E5%BA%95); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E5%BD%92%E6%A0%B9%E5%88%B0%E5%BA%95)</sub>
47. > **当务之急** (dāngwùzhījí)
    > top priority job
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%BD%93%E5%8A%A1%E4%B9%8B%E6%80%A5); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%BD%93%E5%8A%A1%E4%B9%8B%E6%80%A5); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E5%BD%93%E5%8A%A1%E4%B9%8B%E6%80%A5)</sub>
48. > **得不偿失** (débùchángshī)
    > the gains do not make up for the losses (idiom)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%BE%97%E4%B8%8D%E5%81%BF%E5%A4%B1); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%BE%97%E4%B8%8D%E5%81%BF%E5%A4%B1); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E5%BE%97%E4%B8%8D%E5%81%BF%E5%A4%B1)</sub>
49. > **得天独厚** (détiāndúhòu)
    > blessed by heaven (idiom)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%BE%97%E5%A4%A9%E7%8B%AC%E5%8E%9A); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%BE%97%E5%A4%A9%E7%8B%AC%E5%8E%9A); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E5%BE%97%E5%A4%A9%E7%8B%AC%E5%8E%9A)</sub>
50. > **循序渐进** (xúnxùjiànjìn)
    > in sequence, step by step (idiom); to make steady progress incrementally
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%BE%AA%E5%BA%8F%E6%B8%90%E8%BF%9B); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%BE%AA%E5%BA%8F%E6%B8%90%E8%BF%9B); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E5%BE%AA%E5%BA%8F%E6%B8%90%E8%BF%9B)</sub>
51. > **心甘情愿** (xīngānqíngyuàn)
    > delighted to (do sth, idiom)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%BF%83%E7%94%98%E6%83%85%E6%84%BF); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%BF%83%E7%94%98%E6%83%85%E6%84%BF); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E5%BF%83%E7%94%98%E6%83%85%E6%84%BF)</sub>
52. > **急于求成** (jíyúqiúchéng)
    > anxious for quick results (idiom)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%80%A5%E4%BA%8E%E6%B1%82%E6%88%90); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E6%80%A5%E4%BA%8E%E6%B1%82%E6%88%90); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E6%80%A5%E4%BA%8E%E6%B1%82%E6%88%90)</sub>
53. > **急功近利** (jígōngjìnlì)
    > seeking instant benefit (idiom); shortsighted vision, looking only for fast return
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%80%A5%E5%8A%9F%E8%BF%91%E5%88%A9); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E6%80%A5%E5%8A%9F%E8%BF%91%E5%88%A9); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E6%80%A5%E5%8A%9F%E8%BF%91%E5%88%A9)</sub>
54. > **总而言之** (zǒng'éryánzhī)
    > in short
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%80%BB%E8%80%8C%E8%A8%80%E4%B9%8B); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E6%80%BB%E8%80%8C%E8%A8%80%E4%B9%8B); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E6%80%BB%E8%80%8C%E8%A8%80%E4%B9%8B)</sub>
55. > **恍然大悟** (huǎngrándàwù)
    > to suddenly realize
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%81%8D%E7%84%B6%E5%A4%A7%E6%82%9F); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E6%81%8D%E7%84%B6%E5%A4%A7%E6%82%9F); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E6%81%8D%E7%84%B6%E5%A4%A7%E6%82%9F)</sub>
56. > **恰到好处** (qiàdàohǎochù)
    > it's just perfect
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%81%B0%E5%88%B0%E5%A5%BD%E5%A4%84); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E6%81%B0%E5%88%B0%E5%A5%BD%E5%A4%84); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E6%81%B0%E5%88%B0%E5%A5%BD%E5%A4%84)</sub>
57. > **悬崖峭壁** (xuányáqiàobì)
    > sheer cliffs and precipitous rock faces (idiom)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%82%AC%E5%B4%96%E5%B3%AD%E5%A3%81); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E6%82%AC%E5%B4%96%E5%B3%AD%E5%A3%81); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E6%82%AC%E5%B4%96%E5%B3%AD%E5%A3%81)</sub>
58. > **想方设法** (xiǎngfāngshèfǎ)
    > to think up every possible method (idiom); to devise ways and means
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%83%B3%E6%96%B9%E8%AE%BE%E6%B3%95); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E6%83%B3%E6%96%B9%E8%AE%BE%E6%B3%95); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E6%83%B3%E6%96%B9%E8%AE%BE%E6%B3%95)</sub>
59. > **拔苗助长** (bámiáozhùzhǎng)
    > to spoil things through excessive enthusiasm (idiom)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%8B%94%E8%8B%97%E5%8A%A9%E9%95%BF); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E6%8B%94%E8%8B%97%E5%8A%A9%E9%95%BF); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E6%8B%94%E8%8B%97%E5%8A%A9%E9%95%BF)</sub>
60. > **斩钉截铁** (zhǎndīngjiétiě)
    > lit. to chop the nail and slice the iron (idiom)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%96%A9%E9%92%89%E6%88%AA%E9%93%81); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E6%96%A9%E9%92%89%E6%88%AA%E9%93%81); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E6%96%A9%E9%92%89%E6%88%AA%E9%93%81)</sub>
61. > **新陈代谢** (xīnchéndàixiè)
    > metabolism (biology); the new replaces the old (idiom)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%96%B0%E9%99%88%E4%BB%A3%E8%B0%A2); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E6%96%B0%E9%99%88%E4%BB%A3%E8%B0%A2); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E6%96%B0%E9%99%88%E4%BB%A3%E8%B0%A2)</sub>
62. > **无动于衷** (wúdòngyúzhōng)
    > aloof
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%97%A0%E5%8A%A8%E4%BA%8E%E8%A1%B7/4324233); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E6%97%A0%E5%8A%A8%E4%BA%8E%E8%A1%B7); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E6%97%A0%E5%8A%A8%E4%BA%8E%E8%A1%B7)</sub>
63. > **无微不至** (wúwēibùzhì)
    > in every possible way (idiom); meticulous
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%97%A0%E5%BE%AE%E4%B8%8D%E8%87%B3); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E6%97%A0%E5%BE%AE%E4%B8%8D%E8%87%B3); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E6%97%A0%E5%BE%AE%E4%B8%8D%E8%87%B3)</sub>
64. > **无忧无虑** (wúyōuwúlǜ)
    > carefree and without worries (idiom)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%97%A0%E5%BF%A7%E6%97%A0%E8%99%91/84442); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E6%97%A0%E5%BF%A7%E6%97%A0%E8%99%91); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E6%97%A0%E5%BF%A7%E6%97%A0%E8%99%91)</sub>
65. > **无理取闹** (wúlǐqǔnào)
    > to make trouble without reason (idiom); to be deliberately provocative
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%97%A0%E7%90%86%E5%8F%96%E9%97%B9); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E6%97%A0%E7%90%86%E5%8F%96%E9%97%B9); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E6%97%A0%E7%90%86%E5%8F%96%E9%97%B9)</sub>
66. > **无穷无尽** (wúqióngwújìn)
    > endless
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%97%A0%E7%A9%B7%E6%97%A0%E5%B0%BD); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E6%97%A0%E7%A9%B7%E6%97%A0%E5%B0%BD); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E6%97%A0%E7%A9%B7%E6%97%A0%E5%B0%BD)</sub>
67. > **无精打采** (wújīngdǎcǎi)
    > dispirited and downcast (idiom); listless
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%97%A0%E7%B2%BE%E6%89%93%E9%87%87); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E6%97%A0%E7%B2%BE%E6%89%93%E9%87%87); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E6%97%A0%E7%B2%BE%E6%89%93%E9%87%87)</sub>
68. > **无能为力** (wúnéngwéilì)
    > impotent (idiom)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%97%A0%E8%83%BD%E4%B8%BA%E5%8A%9B/33688); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E6%97%A0%E8%83%BD%E4%B8%BA%E5%8A%9B); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E6%97%A0%E8%83%BD%E4%B8%BA%E5%8A%9B)</sub>
69. > **日新月异** (rìxīnyuèyì)
    > daily renewal, monthly change (idiom)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%97%A5%E6%96%B0%E6%9C%88%E5%BC%82); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E6%97%A5%E6%96%B0%E6%9C%88%E5%BC%82); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E6%97%A5%E6%96%B0%E6%9C%88%E5%BC%82)</sub>
70. > **有条不紊** (yǒutiáobùwěn)
    > regular and thorough (idiom); methodically arranged
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%9C%89%E6%9D%A1%E4%B8%8D%E7%B4%8A); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E6%9C%89%E6%9D%A1%E4%B8%8D%E7%B4%8A); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E6%9C%89%E6%9D%A1%E4%B8%8D%E7%B4%8A)</sub>
71. > **朝气蓬勃** (zhāoqìpéngbó)
    > full of youthful energy (idiom); vigorous
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%9C%9D%E6%B0%94%E8%93%AC%E5%8B%83); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E6%9C%9D%E6%B0%94%E8%93%AC%E5%8B%83); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E6%9C%9D%E6%B0%94%E8%93%AC%E5%8B%83)</sub>
72. > **根深蒂固** (gēnshēndìgù)
    > deep-rooted (problem etc)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%A0%B9%E6%B7%B1%E8%92%82%E5%9B%BA); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E6%A0%B9%E6%B7%B1%E8%92%82%E5%9B%BA); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E6%A0%B9%E6%B7%B1%E8%92%82%E5%9B%BA)</sub>
73. > **欣欣向荣** (xīnxīnxiàngróng)
    > (idiom) flourishing
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%AC%A3%E6%AC%A3%E5%90%91%E8%8D%A3); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E6%AC%A3%E6%AC%A3%E5%90%91%E8%8D%A3); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E6%AC%A3%E6%AC%A3%E5%90%91%E8%8D%A3)</sub>
74. > **津津有味** (jīnjīnyǒuwèi)
    > with keen interest pleasure (idiom); with gusto
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%B4%A5%E6%B4%A5%E6%9C%89%E5%91%B3); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E6%B4%A5%E6%B4%A5%E6%9C%89%E5%91%B3); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E6%B4%A5%E6%B4%A5%E6%9C%89%E5%91%B3)</sub>
75. > **深情厚谊** (shēnqínghòuyì)
    > deep friendship
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%B7%B1%E6%83%85%E5%8E%9A%E8%B0%8A); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E6%B7%B1%E6%83%85%E5%8E%9A%E8%B0%8A); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E6%B7%B1%E6%83%85%E5%8E%9A%E8%B0%8A)</sub>
76. > **滔滔不绝** (tāotāobùjué)
    > unceasing torrent (idiom)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%BB%94%E6%BB%94%E4%B8%8D%E7%BB%9D); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E6%BB%94%E6%BB%94%E4%B8%8D%E7%BB%9D); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E6%BB%94%E6%BB%94%E4%B8%8D%E7%BB%9D)</sub>
77. > **潜移默化** (qiányímòhuà)
    > imperceptible influence
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%BD%9C%E7%A7%BB%E9%BB%98%E5%8C%96); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E6%BD%9C%E7%A7%BB%E9%BB%98%E5%8C%96); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E6%BD%9C%E7%A7%BB%E9%BB%98%E5%8C%96)</sub>
78. > **热泪盈眶** (rèlèiyíngkuàng)
    > eyes brimming with tears of excitement (idiom)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%83%AD%E6%B3%AA%E7%9B%88%E7%9C%B6); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E7%83%AD%E6%B3%AA%E7%9B%88%E7%9C%B6); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E7%83%AD%E6%B3%AA%E7%9B%88%E7%9C%B6)</sub>
79. > **爱不释手** (àibùshìshǒu)
    > to love sth too much to part with it (idiom); to fondle admiringly
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%88%B1%E4%B8%8D%E9%87%8A%E6%89%8B/1922); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E7%88%B1%E4%B8%8D%E9%87%8A%E6%89%8B); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E7%88%B1%E4%B8%8D%E9%87%8A%E6%89%8B)</sub>
80. > **物美价廉** (wùměijiàlián)
    > good quality and cheap
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%89%A9%E7%BE%8E%E4%BB%B7%E5%BB%89); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E7%89%A9%E7%BE%8E%E4%BB%B7%E5%BB%89); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E7%89%A9%E7%BE%8E%E4%BB%B7%E5%BB%89)</sub>
81. > **狼吞虎咽** (lángtūnhǔyàn)
    > to wolf down one's food (idiom); to devour ravenously
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%8B%BC%E5%90%9E%E8%99%8E%E5%92%BD); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E7%8B%BC%E5%90%9E%E8%99%8E%E5%92%BD); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E7%8B%BC%E5%90%9E%E8%99%8E%E5%92%BD)</sub>
82. > **理所当然** (lǐsuǒdāngrán)
    > as it should be by rights (idiom)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%90%86%E6%89%80%E5%BD%93%E7%84%B6); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E7%90%86%E6%89%80%E5%BD%93%E7%84%B6); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E7%90%86%E6%89%80%E5%BD%93%E7%84%B6)</sub>
83. > **理直气壮** (lǐzhíqìzhuàng)
    > in the right and self-confident (idiom)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%90%86%E7%9B%B4%E6%B0%94%E5%A3%AE); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E7%90%86%E7%9B%B4%E6%B0%94%E5%A3%AE); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E7%90%86%E7%9B%B4%E6%B0%94%E5%A3%AE)</sub>
84. > **画蛇添足** (huàshétiānzú)
    > lit. draw legs on a snake (idiom); fig. to ruin the effect by adding sth superfluous
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%94%BB%E8%9B%87%E6%B7%BB%E8%B6%B3); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E7%94%BB%E8%9B%87%E6%B7%BB%E8%B6%B3); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E7%94%BB%E8%9B%87%E6%B7%BB%E8%B6%B3)</sub>
85. > **相辅相成** (xiāngfǔxiāngchéng)
    > to complement one another (idiom)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%9B%B8%E8%BE%85%E7%9B%B8%E6%88%90); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E7%9B%B8%E8%BE%85%E7%9B%B8%E6%88%90); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E7%9B%B8%E8%BE%85%E7%9B%B8%E6%88%90)</sub>
86. > **知足常乐** (zhīzúchánglè)
    > satisfied with what one has (idiom)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%9F%A5%E8%B6%B3%E5%B8%B8%E4%B9%90/62528); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E7%9F%A5%E8%B6%B3%E5%B8%B8%E4%B9%90); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E7%9F%A5%E8%B6%B3%E5%B8%B8%E4%B9%90)</sub>
87. > **礼尚往来** (lǐshàngwǎnglái)
    > lit. proper behavior is based on reciprocity (idiom)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%A4%BC%E5%B0%9A%E5%BE%80%E6%9D%A5); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E7%A4%BC%E5%B0%9A%E5%BE%80%E6%9D%A5); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E7%A4%BC%E5%B0%9A%E5%BE%80%E6%9D%A5)</sub>
88. > **称心如意** (chènxīnrúyì)
    > after one's heart (idiom); gratifying and satisfactory
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%A7%B0%E5%BF%83%E5%A6%82%E6%84%8F/5975); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E7%A7%B0%E5%BF%83%E5%A6%82%E6%84%8F); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E7%A7%B0%E5%BF%83%E5%A6%82%E6%84%8F)</sub>
89. > **空前绝后** (kōngqiánjuéhòu)
    > unprecedented and never to be duplicated
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%A9%BA%E5%89%8D%E7%BB%9D%E5%90%8E); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E7%A9%BA%E5%89%8D%E7%BB%9D%E5%90%8E); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E7%A9%BA%E5%89%8D%E7%BB%9D%E5%90%8E)</sub>
90. > **竭尽全力** (jiéjìnquánlì)
    > to spare no effort (idiom); to do one's utmost
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%AB%AD%E5%B0%BD%E5%85%A8%E5%8A%9B); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E7%AB%AD%E5%B0%BD%E5%85%A8%E5%8A%9B); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E7%AB%AD%E5%B0%BD%E5%85%A8%E5%8A%9B)</sub>
91. > **精打细算** (jīngdǎxìsuàn)
    > meticulous planning and careful accounting (idiom)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%B2%BE%E6%89%93%E7%BB%86%E7%AE%97); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E7%B2%BE%E6%89%93%E7%BB%86%E7%AE%97); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E7%B2%BE%E6%89%93%E7%BB%86%E7%AE%97)</sub>
92. > **精益求精** (jīngyìqiújīng)
    > to perfect sth that is already outstanding (idiom); constantly improving
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%B2%BE%E7%9B%8A%E6%B1%82%E7%B2%BE); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E7%B2%BE%E7%9B%8A%E6%B1%82%E7%B2%BE); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E7%B2%BE%E7%9B%8A%E6%B1%82%E7%B2%BE)</sub>
93. > **络绎不绝** (luòyìbùjué)
    > continuously; in an endless stream (idiom)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%BB%9C%E7%BB%8E%E4%B8%8D%E7%BB%9D); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E7%BB%9C%E7%BB%8E%E4%B8%8D%E7%BB%9D); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E7%BB%9C%E7%BB%8E%E4%B8%8D%E7%BB%9D)</sub>
94. > **统筹兼顾** (tǒngchóujiāngù)
    > an overall plan taking into account all factors
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%BB%9F%E7%AD%B9%E5%85%BC%E9%A1%BE); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E7%BB%9F%E7%AD%B9%E5%85%BC%E9%A1%BE); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E7%BB%9F%E7%AD%B9%E5%85%BC%E9%A1%BE)</sub>
95. > **聚精会神** (jùjīnghuìshén)
    > to concentrate one's attention (idiom)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%81%9A%E7%B2%BE%E4%BC%9A%E7%A5%9E); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E8%81%9A%E7%B2%BE%E4%BC%9A%E7%A5%9E); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E8%81%9A%E7%B2%BE%E4%BC%9A%E7%A5%9E)</sub>
96. > **肆无忌惮** (sìwújìdàn)
    > absolutely unrestrained
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%82%86%E6%97%A0%E5%BF%8C%E6%83%AE); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E8%82%86%E6%97%A0%E5%BF%8C%E6%83%AE); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E8%82%86%E6%97%A0%E5%BF%8C%E6%83%AE)</sub>
97. > **自力更生** (zìlìgēngshēng)
    > regeneration through one's own effort (idiom)
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%87%AA%E5%8A%9B%E6%9B%B4%E7%94%9F); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E8%87%AA%E5%8A%9B%E6%9B%B4%E7%94%9F); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E8%87%AA%E5%8A%9B%E6%9B%B4%E7%94%9F)</sub>
98. > **苦尽甘来** (kǔjìngānlái)
    > bitterness finishes, sweetness begins (idiom); the hard times are over, the good times just beginning
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%8B%A6%E5%B0%BD%E7%94%98%E6%9D%A5); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E8%8B%A6%E5%B0%BD%E7%94%98%E6%9D%A5); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E8%8B%A6%E5%B0%BD%E7%94%98%E6%9D%A5)</sub>
99. > **莫名其妙** (mòmíngqímiào)
    > (idiom) baffling
    > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%8E%AB%E5%90%8D%E5%85%B6%E5%A6%99); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E8%8E%AB%E5%90%8D%E5%85%B6%E5%A6%99); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E8%8E%AB%E5%90%8D%E5%85%B6%E5%A6%99)</sub>
100. > **见义勇为** (jiànyìyǒngwéi)
     > to see what is right and act courageously (idiom, from Analects)
     > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%A7%81%E4%B9%89%E5%8B%87%E4%B8%BA); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E8%A7%81%E4%B9%89%E5%8B%87%E4%B8%BA); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E8%A7%81%E4%B9%89%E5%8B%87%E4%B8%BA)</sub>
101. > **见多识广** (jiànduōshìguǎng)
     > experienced and knowledgeable (idiom)
     > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%A7%81%E5%A4%9A%E8%AF%86%E5%B9%BF); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E8%A7%81%E5%A4%9A%E8%AF%86%E5%B9%BF); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E8%A7%81%E5%A4%9A%E8%AF%86%E5%B9%BF)</sub>
102. > **迄今为止** (qìjīnwéizhǐ)
     > so far
     > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%BF%84%E4%BB%8A%E4%B8%BA%E6%AD%A2); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E8%BF%84%E4%BB%8A%E4%B8%BA%E6%AD%A2); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E8%BF%84%E4%BB%8A%E4%B8%BA%E6%AD%A2)</sub>
103. > **迫不及待** (pòbùjídài)
     > impatient (idiom); in a hurry
     > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%BF%AB%E4%B8%8D%E5%8F%8A%E5%BE%85); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E8%BF%AB%E4%B8%8D%E5%8F%8A%E5%BE%85); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E8%BF%AB%E4%B8%8D%E5%8F%8A%E5%BE%85)</sub>
104. > **锦上添花** (jǐnshàngtiānhuā)
     > lit. on brocade, add flowers (idiom); to decorate sth already perfect
     > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E9%94%A6%E4%B8%8A%E6%B7%BB%E8%8A%B1); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E9%94%A6%E4%B8%8A%E6%B7%BB%E8%8A%B1); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E9%94%A6%E4%B8%8A%E6%B7%BB%E8%8A%B1)</sub>
105. > **锲而不舍** (qiè'érbùshě)
     > to chip away at a task and not abandon it (idiom); to chisel away at sth
     > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E9%94%B2%E8%80%8C%E4%B8%8D%E8%88%8D); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E9%94%B2%E8%80%8C%E4%B8%8D%E8%88%8D); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E9%94%B2%E8%80%8C%E4%B8%8D%E8%88%8D)</sub>
106. > **难能可贵** (nánnéngkěguì)
     > rare and precious
     > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E9%9A%BE%E8%83%BD%E5%8F%AF%E8%B4%B5); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E9%9A%BE%E8%83%BD%E5%8F%AF%E8%B4%B5); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E9%9A%BE%E8%83%BD%E5%8F%AF%E8%B4%B5)</sub>
107. > **雪上加霜** (xuěshàngjiāshuāng)
     > to add hail to snow (idiom); one disaster on top of another
     > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E9%9B%AA%E4%B8%8A%E5%8A%A0%E9%9C%9C); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E9%9B%AA%E4%B8%8A%E5%8A%A0%E9%9C%9C); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E9%9B%AA%E4%B8%8A%E5%8A%A0%E9%9C%9C)</sub>
108. > **风土人情** (fēngtǔrénqíng)
     > local conditions and customs (idiom)
     > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E9%A3%8E%E5%9C%9F%E4%BA%BA%E6%83%85); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E9%A3%8E%E5%9C%9F%E4%BA%BA%E6%83%85); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E9%A3%8E%E5%9C%9F%E4%BA%BA%E6%83%85)</sub>
109. > **饱经沧桑** (bǎojīngcāngsāng)
     > having lived through many changes
     > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E9%A5%B1%E7%BB%8F%E6%B2%A7%E6%A1%91); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E9%A5%B1%E7%BB%8F%E6%B2%A7%E6%A1%91); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E9%A5%B1%E7%BB%8F%E6%B2%A7%E6%A1%91)</sub>
110. > **鸦雀无声** (yāquèwúshēng)
     > lit. crow and peacock make no sound; absolute silence (idiom)
     > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E9%B8%A6%E9%9B%80%E6%97%A0%E5%A3%B0/1104840); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E9%B8%A6%E9%9B%80%E6%97%A0%E5%A3%B0); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E9%B8%A6%E9%9B%80%E6%97%A0%E5%A3%B0)</sub>
111. > **齐心协力** (qíxīnxiélì)
     > to work with a common purpose (idiom); to make concerted efforts
     > <sub>[Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E9%BD%90%E5%BF%83%E5%8D%8F%E5%8A%9B); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E9%BD%90%E5%BF%83%E5%8D%8F%E5%8A%9B); [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E9%BD%90%E5%BF%83%E5%8D%8F%E5%8A%9B)</sub>

Not counted: 二氧化碳 (carbon dioxide), 公共汽车 (bus), 名胜古迹 (historical sites), 微不足道 (negligible), 烟花爆竹 (firecrackers), 电子邮件 (email), 高速公路 (expressway), 通货膨胀 (inflation), 飞禽走兽 (birds and animals), 讨价还价 (haggle over price).

Answer (score 4):

This is for the new HSK 3.0 vocabulary (405 total; some definitions pruned for space; some are debatable):

| chengyu | pinyin | CC-CEDICT definition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 一路平安 | yīlùpíngān | to have a pleasant journey; Bon voyage! |
| 一路顺风 | yīlùshùnfēng | to have a pleasant journey (idiom) |
| 五颜六色 | wǔyánliùsè | multi-colored; every color under the sun |
| 酸甜苦辣 | suāntiánkǔlà | sour, sweet, bitter and spicy hot; fig. the joys and sorrows of life |
| 不怎么样 | bùzěnmeyàng | not up to much; very indifferent; nothing great about it |
| 绝大多数 | juédàduōshù | absolute majority; overwhelming majority |
| 一模一样 | yīmúyīyàng | exactly the same (idiom); carbon copy |
| 自言自语 | zìyánzìyǔ | to talk to oneself; to think aloud; to soliloquize |
| 爱不释手 | àibùshìshǒu | to love sth too much to part with it (idiom); to fondle admiringly |
| 爱理不理 | àilǐbùlǐ | to look cold and indifferent; standoffish |
| 半途而废 | bàntúérfèi | to give up halfway (idiom); leave sth unfinished |
| 半信半疑 | bànxìnbànyí | half doubting; dubious; skeptical |
| 半真半假 | bànzhēnbànjiǎ | (idiom) half true and half false |
| 暴风骤雨 | bàofēngzhòuyǔ | violent wind and rainstorm; hurricane; tempest |
| 悲欢离合 | bēihuānlíhé | joys and sorrows; partings and reunions; the vicissitudes of life |
| 比比皆是 | bǐbǐjiēshì | can be found everywhere |
| 必不可少 | bìbùkěshǎo | absolutely necessary; indispensable; essential |
| 变幻莫测 | biànhuànmòcè | to change unpredictably; unpredictable; erratic; treacherous |
| 别具匠心 | biéjùjiàngxīn | to show ingenuity; (of a design) clever; brilliantly conceived |
| 彬彬有礼 | bīnbīnyǒulǐ | refined and courteous; urbane |
| 不亦乐乎 | bùyìlèhū | lit. isn't that a joy? (quote from Confucius); fig. (jocular) extremely; awfully |
| 不翼而飞 | bùyìérfēi | to disappear without trace; to spread like wildfire |
| 不正之风 | bùzhèngzhīfēng | unhealthy tendency |
| 不耻下问 | bùchǐxiàwèn | not feel ashamed to ask and learn from one's subordinates |
| 不辞而别 | bùcíérbié | to leave without saying good-bye |
| 不得而知 | bùdéérzhī | unknown; unable to find out |
| 不假思索 | bùjiǎsīsuǒ | to act without taking time to think (idiom); to react instantly |
| 不可避免 | bùkěbìmiǎn | unavoidably |
| 不可思议 | bùkěsīyì | inconceivable (idiom); unimaginable; unfathomable |
| 不了了之 | bùliǎoliǎozhī | to settle a matter by leaving it unsettled; to end up with nothing definite |
| 不同寻常 | bùtóngxúncháng | out of the ordinary; unusual |
| 不为人知 | bùwéirénzhī | not known to anyone; secret; unknown |
| 不相上下 | bùxiāngshàngxià | equally matched; about the same |
| 不以为然 | bùyǐwéirán | not to accept as correct (idiom); to object; to disapprove; to take exception to |
| 不由自主 | bùyóuzìzhǔ | can't help; involuntarily (idiom) |
| 不约而同 | bùyuēértóng | to agree by chance (idiom); taking the same action without prior consultation |
| 不知不觉 | bùzhībùjué | unconsciously; unwittingly |
| 层出不穷 | céngchūbùqióng | more and more emerge; innumerable succession; breeding like flies (idiom) |
| 成千上万 | chéngqiānshàngwàn | lit. by the thousands and tens of thousands (idiom); innumerable |
| 成群结队 | chéngqúnjiéduì | making up a group, forming a troupe (idiom); in large numbers; as a large crowd |
| 诚心诚意 | chéngxīnchéngyì | earnestly and sincerely (idiom); with all sincerity |
| 乘人之危 | chéngrénzhīwēi | to take advantage of sb's precarious position |
| 吃喝玩乐 | chīhēwánlè | to eat, drink and be merry (idiom); to abandon oneself to a life of pleasure |
| 持之以恒 | chízhīyǐhéng | to pursue unremittingly (idiom); to persevere |
| 愁眉苦脸 | chóuméikǔliǎn | to look anxious (idiom); to look miserable |
| 出口成章 | chūkǒuchéngzhāng | (idiom) (of one's speech) eloquent; articulate |
| 出人意料 | chūrényìliào | unexpected (idiom); surprising |
| 触目惊心 | chùmùjīngxīn | lit. shocks the eye, astonishes the heart (idiom); a ghastly sight |
| 川流不息 | chuānliúbùxī | the stream flows without stopping (idiom); unending flow |
| 垂头丧气 | chuítóusàngqì | hanging one's head dispiritedly (idiom); dejected; crestfallen |
| 此起彼伏 | cǐqǐbǐfú | up here, down there (idiom); to rise and fall in succession |
| 从容不迫 | cóngróngbùpò | calm; unruffled |
| 粗心大意 | cūxīndàyì | negligent; careless; inadvertent |
| 措手不及 | cuòshǒubùjí | no time to deal with it (idiom); caught unprepared |
| 错综复杂 | cuòzōngfùzá | tangled and complicated (idiom) |
| 大包大揽 | dàbāodàlǎn | to take complete charge (idiom) |
| 大吃一惊 | dàchīyījīng | to have a surprise (idiom); shocked or startled; gobsmacked |
| 大大咧咧 | dàdàliēliē | carefree; offhand; casual |
| 大公无私 | dàgōngwúsī | selfless; impartial |
| 大街小巷 | dàjiēxiǎoxiàng | great streets and small alleys (idiom); everywhere in the city |
| 大惊小怪 | dàjīngxiǎoguài | to make a fuss about nothing (idiom) |
| 大名鼎鼎 | dàmíngdǐngdǐng | grand reputation; renowned; famous |
| 大模大样 | dàmúdàyàng | boldly; ostentatiously; poised; self-assured |
| 大同小异 | dàtóngxiǎoyì | virtually the same; differing only on small points |
| 大有可为 | dàyǒukěwéi | with great prospects for the future (idiom); well worth doing |
| 当务之急 | dāngwùzhījí | top priority job; matter of vital importance |
| 当之无愧 | dāngzhīwúkuì | fully deserving, without any reservations (idiom); entirely worthy (of a title, honor etc) |
| 得不偿失 | débùchángshī | the gains do not make up for the losses (idiom) |
| 得天独厚 | détiāndúhòu | blessed by heaven (idiom); enjoying exceptional advantages; favored by nature |
| 得意扬扬 | déyìyángyáng | joyfully satisfied; to be immensely proud of oneself; proudly; an air of complacency |
| 东奔西走 | dōngbēnxīzǒu | to run this way and that (idiom); to rush about busily; to bustle about; to hopscotch |
| 东张西望 | dōngzhāngxīwàng | to look in all directions (idiom); to glance around |
| 独立自主 | dúlìzìzhǔ | independent and autonomous (idiom); self-determination |
| 独一无二 | dúyīwúèr | unique and unmatched (idiom); unrivalled; nothing compares with it |
| 多劳多得 | duōláoduōdé | work more and get more |
| 耳目一新 | ěrmùyīxīn | a pleasant change; a breath of fresh air; refreshing |
| 耳熟能详 | ěrshúnéngxiáng | what's frequently heard can be repeated in detail (idiom) |
| 耳闻目睹 | ěrwénmùdǔ | to witness personally |
| 发愤图强 | fāfèntúqiáng | to be strongly determined to succeed (idiom) |
| 发扬光大 | fāyángguāngdà | to develop and promote; to carry forward; to bring to great height of development |
| 翻天覆地 | fāntiānfùdì | sky and the earth turning upside down (idiom); fig. complete confusion; everything turned on its head |
| 方方面面 | fāngfāngmiànmiàn | all sides; all aspects; multi-faceted |
| 废寝忘食 | fèiqǐnwàngshí | to neglect sleep and forget about food (idiom); to be completely wrapped up in one's work |
| 沸沸扬扬 | fèifèiyángyáng | bubbling and gurgling; hubbubing; abuzz |
| 丰富多彩 | fēngfùduōcǎi | richly colorful |
| 风餐露宿 | fēngcānlùsù | lit. to eat in the open air and sleep outdoors (idiom); fig. to rough it |
| 风风雨雨 | fēngfēngyǔyǔ | trials and tribulations; ups and downs |
| 风和日丽 | fēnghérìlì | moderate wind, beautiful sun (idiom); fine sunny weather, esp. in springtime |
| 峰回路转 | fēnghuílùzhuǎn | the mountain road twists around each new peak (idiom); (of a mountain road) twisting and turning; fig. an opportunity has come unexpectedly |
| 改邪归正 | gǎixiéguīzhèng | to mend one's ways (idiom); to turn over a new leaf |
| 格格不入 | gégébùrù | (idiom) inharmonious; incompatible |
| 各奔前程 | gèbènqiánchéng | each goes his own way (idiom); each person has his own life to lead |
| 根深蒂固 | gēnshēndìgù | deep-rooted (problem etc) |
| 供不应求 | gōngbùyìngqiú | supply does not meet demand |
| 沽名钓誉 | gūmíngdiàoyù | to angle for fame (idiom); to fish for compliments |
| 孤陋寡闻 | gūlòuguǎwén | ignorant and inexperienced; ill-informed and narrow-minded |
| 古今中外 | gǔjīnzhōngwài | at all times and in all places (idiom) |
| 顾全大局 | gùquándàjú | to take the big picture into consideration (idiom); to work for the benefits of all |
| 光明磊落 | guāngmínglěiluò | open and candid (idiom); straightforward and upright |
| 归根到底 | guīgēndàodǐ | after all; in the final analysis; ultimately |
| 过意不去 | guòyìbùqù | to feel very apologetic |
| 骇人听闻 | hàiréntīngwén | shocking; horrifying; atrocious; terrible |
| 毫不犹豫 | háobùyóuyù | without the slightest hesitation |
| 合情合理 | héqínghélǐ | reasonable and fair (idiom) |
| 鹤立鸡群 | hèlìjīqún | a crane in a flock of chicken (idiom); way above the common; manifestly superior |
| 横七竖八 | héngqīshùbā | in disorder; at sixes and sevens (idiom) |
| 哄堂大笑 | hōngtángdàxiào | the whole room roaring with laughter (idiom) |
| 后顾之忧 | hòugùzhīyōu | fears of trouble in the rear (idiom); family worries (obstructing freedom of action); worries about the future consequences |
| 呼风唤雨 | hūfēnghuànyǔ | to call the wind and summon the rain (idiom); to exercise magical powers; fig. to stir up troubles |
| 忽高忽低 | hūgāohūdī | alternately soaring and plunging |
| 胡思乱想 | húsīluànxiǎng | to indulge in flights of fancy (idiom); to let one's imagination run wild |
| 化险为夷 | huàxiǎnwéiyí | to turn peril into safety (idiom); to avert disaster |
| 画龙点睛 | huàlóngdiǎnjīng | to paint a dragon and dot in the eyes (idiom); fig. to add the vital finishing touch |
| 画蛇添足 | huàshétiānzú | lit. draw legs on a snake (idiom); fig. to ruin the effect by adding sth superfluous; to overdo it |
| 欢声笑语 | huānshēngxiàoyǔ | cheers and laughter |
| 恍然大悟 | huǎngrándàwù | to suddenly realize; to suddenly see the light |
| 绘声绘色 | huìshēnghuìsè | vivid and colorful (idiom); true to life; lively and realistic |
| 或多或少 | huòduōhuòshǎo | more or less |
| 记忆犹新 | jìyìyóuxīn | to remain fresh in one's memory (idiom) |
| 家家户户 | jiājiāhùhù | each and every family (idiom); every household |
| 家喻户晓 | jiāyùhùxiǎo | understood by everyone (idiom); well known; a household name |
| 坚持不懈 | jiānchíbùxiè | to persevere unremittingly (idiom); to keep going until the end |
| 艰苦奋斗 | jiānkǔfèndòu | to struggle arduously |
| 见钱眼开 | jiànqiányǎnkāi | to open one's eyes wide at the sight of profit (idiom); thinking of nothing but personal gain; money-grubbing |
| 见仁见智 | jiànrénjiànzhì | opinions differ (idiom) |
| 见义勇为 | jiànyìyǒngwéi | to see what is right and act courageously (idiom, from Analects) |
| 交头接耳 | jiāotóujiēěr | to whisper to one another's ear |
| 接二连三 | jiēèrliánsān | one after another (idiom); in quick succession |
| 节衣缩食 | jiéyīsuōshí | to save on food and clothing (idiom); to live frugally |
| 竭尽全力 | jiéjìnquánlì | to spare no effort (idiom); to do one's utmost |
| 津津有味 | jīnjīnyǒuwèi | with keen interest (idiom); with great pleasure |
| 经久不息 | jīngjiǔbùxī | prolonged (applause, cheering etc) |
| 惊慌失措 | jīnghuāngshīcuò | to lose one's head out of fear (idiom) |
| 惊天动地 | jīngtiāndòngdì | world-shaking (idiom) |
| 惊心动魄 | jīngxīndòngpò | shaking one to the core; extremely disturbing; hair-raising (idiom) |
| 兢兢业业 | jīngjīngyèyè | (idiom) conscientious; assiduous |
| 精打细算 | jīngdǎxìsuàn | meticulous planning and careful accounting (idiom) |
| 精疲力竭 | jīngpílìjié | spirit weary, strength exhausted (idiom); spent; drained; washed out |
| 精益求精 | jīngyìqiújīng | to perfect sth that is already outstanding (idiom); constantly improving |
| 敬而远之 | jìngéryuǎnzhī | to show respect from a distance (idiom); to remain at a respectful distance |
| 居高临下 | jūgāolínxià | lit. to be in a high location, overlooking the scene below (idiom); fig. to occupy a commanding position; to assume a haughty attitude |
| 举世闻名 | jǔshìwénmíng | world-famous (idiom) |
| 举世无双 | jǔshìwúshuāng | unrivaled (idiom); world number one; unique; unequaled |
| 举世瞩目 | jǔshìzhǔmù | to receive worldwide attention |
| 举一反三 | jǔyīfǎnsān | to raise one and infer three; to deduce many things from one case (idiom) |
| 聚精会神 | jùjīnghuìshén | to concentrate one's attention (idiom) |
| 开天辟地 | kāitiānpìdì | to split heaven and earth apart (idiom); refers to the Pangu 盤古 |
| 可乘之机 | kěchéngzhījī | an opportunity that someone (usually a villain or adversary) can exploit |
| 可歌可泣 | kěgēkěqì | lit. you can sing or you can cry (idiom); fig. deeply moving; happy and sad; inspiring and tragic |
| 可想而知 | kěxiǎngérzhī | it is obvious that... |
| 刻舟求剑 | kèzhōuqiújiàn | lit. a notch on the side of a boat to locate a sword dropped overboard (idiom); fig. an action made pointless by changed circumstances |
| 扣人心弦 | kòurénxīnxián | to excite; to thrill; exciting; thrilling |
| 哭笑不得 | kūxiàobùdé | lit. not to know whether to laugh or cry (idiom); both funny and extremely embarrassing; between laughter and tears |
| 夸夸其谈 | kuākuāqítán | to talk big; to sound off |
| 来龙去脉 | láilóngqùmài | the rise and fall of the terrain (idiom); (fig.) the whole sequence of events; causes and effects |
| 冷酷无情 | lěngkùwúqíng | cold-hearted; unfeeling; callous |
| 理所当然 | lǐsuǒdāngrán | as it should be by rights (idiom); proper and to be expected as a matter of course |
| 理直气壮 | lǐzhíqìzhuàng | in the right and self-confident (idiom); bold and confident with justice on one's side |
| 力不从心 | lìbùcóngxīn | less capable than desirable (idiom); the spirit is willing but the flesh is weak |
| 力所能及 | lìsuǒnéngjí | as far as one's capabilities extend (idiom); to the best of one's ability; within one's powers |
| 连滚带爬 | liángǔndàipá | rolling and crawling; trying frantically to escape (idiom) |
| 恋恋不舍 | liànliànbùshě | reluctant to part |
| 寥寥无几 | liáoliáowújǐ | just a very few (idiom); tiny number; not many at all; You count them on your fingers. |
| 灵机一动 | língjīyīdòng | a bright idea suddenly occurs (idiom); to hit upon an inspiration; to be struck by a brainwave |
| 乱七八糟 | luànqībāzāo | everything in disorder (idiom); in a hideous mess; at sixes and sevens |
| 络绎不绝 | luòyìbùjué | continuously; in an endless stream (idiom) |
| 没完没了 | méiwánméiliǎo | without end; incessantly; on and on |
| 眉开眼笑 | méikāiyǎnxiào | brows raised in delight, eyes laughing (idiom); beaming with joy; all smiles |
| 美中不足 | měizhōngbùzú | everything is fine except for one small defect (idiom); the fly in the ointment |
| 门当户对 | méndānghùduì | the families are well-matched in terms of social status (idiom); (of a prospective marriage partner) an appropriate match |
| 迷惑不解 | míhuòbùjiě | to feel puzzled |
| 密不可分 | mìbùkěfēn | inextricably linked (idiom); inseparable |
| 面红耳赤 | miànhóngěrchì | flushed with anger (or excitement) |
| 面面俱到 | miànmiànjùdào | (idiom) take care of everything; handle everything |
| 面目全非 | miànmùquánfēi | nothing remains the same (idiom); change beyond recognition |
| 名副其实 | míngfùqíshí | not just in name only, but also in reality (idiom); aptly named; worthy of the name |
| 莫名其妙 | mòmíngqímiào | (idiom) baffling; inexplicable |
| 默默无闻 | mòmòwúwén | obscure and unknown (idiom); an outsider without any reputation |
| 目不转睛 | mùbùzhuǎnjīng | unable to take one's eyes off (idiom); to gaze steadily; to stare |
| 目瞪口呆 | mùdèngkǒudāi | dumbstruck (idiom); stupefied; stunned |
| 目中无人 | mùzhōngwúrén | to consider everyone else beneath one (idiom); so arrogant that no-one else matters; condescending |
| 耐人寻味 | nàirénxúnwèi | thought-provoking; worth thinking over; to provide food for thought |
| 难得一见 | nándéyījiàn | rarely seen |
| 难以置信 | nányǐzhìxìn | hard to believe; incredible |
| 恼羞成怒 | nǎoxiūchéngnù | to fly into a rage out of humiliation; to be ashamed into anger (idiom) |
| 念念不忘 | niànniànbùwàng | to keep in mind constantly (idiom) |
| 弄虚作假 | nòngxūzuòjiǎ | to practice fraud (idiom); by trickery |
| 鹏程万里 | péngchéngwànlǐ | the fabled roc flies ten thousand miles (idiom); one's future prospects are brilliant |
| 疲惫不堪 | píbèibùkān | exhausted; fatigued to the extreme |
| 萍水相逢 | píngshuǐxiāngféng | strangers coming together by chance (idiom) |
| 迫不及待 | pòbùjídài | impatient (idiom); in a hurry; itching to get on with it |
| 扑面而来 | pūmiànérlái | lit. sth hits one in the face; directly in one's face; sth assaults the senses; blatant (advertising) |
| 七嘴八舌 | qīzuǐbāshé | lively discussion with everybody talking at once |
| 齐心协力 | qíxīnxiélì | to work with a common purpose (idiom); to pull together |
| 奇花异草 | qíhuāyìcǎo | very rarely seen, unusual (idiom) |
| 岂有此理 | qǐyǒucǐlǐ | how can this be so? (idiom); preposterous; ridiculous; absurd |
| 迄今为止 | qìjīnwéizhǐ | so far; up to now; still (not) |
| 恰到好处 | qiàdàohǎochù | it's just perfect; it's just right |
| 恰恰相反 | qiàqiàxiāngfǎn | just the opposite |
| 恰如其分 | qiàrúqífèn | (idiom) appropriate; apt; just right |
| 千变万化 | qiānbiànwànhuà | countless changes; constant permutation |
| 千方百计 | qiānfāngbǎijì | lit. thousand ways, a hundred plans (idiom); by every possible means |
| 千家万户 | qiānjiāwànhù | every family (idiom) |
| 千军万马 | qiānjūnwànmǎ | magnificent army with thousands of men and horses (idiom); impressive display of manpower |
| 千钧一发 | qiānjūnyīfà | a thousand pounds hangs by a thread (idiom); imminent peril; a matter of life or death |
| 前赴后继 | qiánfùhòujì | to advance dauntlessly in wave upon wave (idiom) |
| 前所未有 | qiánsuǒwèiyǒu | unprecedented |
| 前无古人 | qiánwúgǔrén | (idiom) unprecedented; unheard of |
| 前仰后合 | qiányǎnghòuhé | to sway to and fro; to rock back and forth |
| 潜移默化 | qiányímòhuà | imperceptible influence; to influence secretly |
| 亲朋好友 | qīnpénghǎoyǒu | friends and family; kith and kin |
| 勤工俭学 | qíngōngjiǎnxué | to work part time while studying; work-study program |
| 轻而易举 | qīngéryìjǔ | easy; with no difficulty |
| 倾家荡产 | qīngjiādàngchǎn | to lose a family fortune (idiom) |
| 情不自禁 | qíngbùzìjīn | unable to restrain emotions; cannot help |
| 取而代之 | qǔérdàizhī | to substitute for sb; to remove and replace |
| 全力以赴 | quánlìyǐfù | to do at all costs; to make an all-out effort |
| 全心全意 | quánxīnquányì | heart and soul; wholeheartedly |
| 忍饥挨饿 | rěnjīáiè | starving; famished |
| 任人宰割 | rènrénzǎigē | to get trampled on (idiom); to be taken advantage of |
| 日复一日 | rìfùyīrì | day after day |
| 日新月异 | rìxīnyuèyì | daily renewal, monthly change (idiom); rapid progress |
| 容光焕发 | róngguānghuànfā | face glowing (idiom); looking radiant |
| 如愿以偿 | rúyuànyǐcháng | to have one's wish fulfilled |
| 如醉如痴 | rúzuìrúchī | lit. as if drunk and stupefied (idiom); intoxicated by sth; obsessed with; mad about sth |
| 三番五次 | sānfānwǔcì | over and over again (idiom) |
| 身不由己 | shēnbùyóujǐ | without the freedom to act independently (idiom); involuntary |
| 深入人心 | shēnrùrénxīn | to enter deeply into people's hearts; to have a real impact on the people (idiom) |
| 盛气凌人 | shèngqìlíngrén | overbearing; arrogant bully |
| 时好时坏 | shíhǎoshíhuài | sometimes good, sometimes bad |
| 实话实说 | shíhuàshíshuō | to tell the truth; to tell it as it is |
| 实事求是 | shíshìqiúshì | to seek truth from facts (idiom); to be practical and realistic |
| 史无前例 | shǐwúqiánlì | unprecedented in history |
| 势不可当 | shìbùkědāng | impossible to resist (idiom); an irresistible force |
| 守株待兔 | shǒuzhūdàitù | lit. to guard a tree-stump, waiting for rabbits (idiom); to wait idly for opportunities |
| 水落石出 | shuǐluòshíchū | as the water recedes, the rocks appear (idiom); the truth comes to light |
| 水涨船高 | shuǐzhǎngchuángāo | the tide rises, the boat floats (idiom); to develop according to the situation |
| 顺理成章 | shùnlǐchéngzhāng | logical; only to be expected; rational and clearly structured (of text) |
| 顺其自然 | shùnqízìrán | to let nature take its course (idiom) |
| 说干就干 | shuōgànjiùgàn | to do what needs to be done, without delay |
| 说老实话 | shuōlǎoshihuà | to be honest; to tell the truth; to be frank |
| 司空见惯 | sīkōngjiànguàn | a common occurrence (idiom) |
| 思前想后 | sīqiánxiǎnghòu | to consider past cause and future effect (idiom); to think over the past and future; to ponder over reasons and connection |
| 死心塌地 | sǐxīntādì | to be hell-bent on; dead set on sth; unswerving |
| 四面八方 | sìmiànbāfāng | in all directions; all around; far and near |
| 似曾相识 | sìcéngxiāngshí | déjà vu; seemingly familiar; apparently already acquainted |
| 似是而非 | sìshìérfēi | apparently right but actually wrong; specious (idiom) |
| 素不相识 | sùbùxiāngshí | to be total strangers (idiom) |
| 随处可见 | suíchùkějiàn | can be seen everywhere |
| 随时随地 | suíshísuídì | anytime and anywhere |
| 随心所欲 | suíxīnsuǒyù | to follow one's heart's desires; to do as one pleases (idiom) |
| 损人利己 | sǔnrénlìjǐ | harming others for one's personal benefit (idiom); personal gain to the detriment of others |
| 所作所为 | suǒzuòsuǒwéi | one's conduct and deeds |
| 滔滔不绝 | tāotāobùjué | unceasing torrent (idiom); talking non-stop; gabbling forty to the dozen |
| 讨人喜欢 | tǎorénxǐhuan | to attract people's affection; delightful |
| 提心吊胆 | tíxīndiàodǎn | (saying) to be very scared and on edge |
| 天长地久 | tiānchángdìjiǔ | enduring while the world lasts (idiom); eternal |
| 天经地义 | tiānjīngdìyì | lit. heaven's law and earth's principle (idiom); fig. right and proper; right and unalterable; a matter of course |
| 同舟共济 | tóngzhōugòngjì | cross a river in the same boat (idiom); fig. having common interests |
| 头头是道 | tóutóushìdào | clear and logical |
| 突如其来 | tūrúqílái | to arise abruptly; to arrive suddenly; happening suddenly |
| 土生土长 | tǔshēngtǔzhǎng | locally born and bred; indigenous; home-grown |
| 脱口而出 | tuōkǒuérchū | to blurt out; to let slip (an indiscreet remark) |
| 脱颖而出 | tuōyǐngérchū | to reveal one's talent (idiom); to distinguish oneself |
| 万古长青 | wàngǔchángqīng | remain fresh; last forever; eternal |
| 万无一失 | wànwúyīshī | surefire; absolutely safe (idiom) |
| 亡羊补牢 | wángyángbǔláo | lit. to mend the pen after sheep are lost (idiom); fig. to act belatedly; better late than never |
| 微不足道 | wēibùzúdào | negligible; insignificant |
| 无恶不作 | wúèbùzuò | not to shrink from any crime (idiom); to commit any imaginable misdeed |
| 无关紧要 | wúguānjǐnyào | indifferent; insignificant |
| 无话可说 | wúhuàkěshuō | to have nothing to say (idiom) |
| 无济于事 | wújìyúshì | to no avail; of no use |
| 无精打采 | wújīngdǎcǎi | dispirited and downcast (idiom); listless; in low spirits; washed out |
| 无可奉告 | wúkěfènggào | (idiom) "no comment" |
| 无可厚非 | wúkěhòufēi | not to be censured too strictly (idiom); not altogether inexcusable; understandable |
| 无可奈何 | wúkěnàihé | have no way out; have no alternative; abbr. to 無奈 |
| 无论如何 | wúlùnrúhé | whatever the case; in any event; no matter what; by all possible means |
| 无能为力 | wúnéngwéilì | impotent (idiom); powerless |
| 无情无义 | wúqíngwúyì | completely lacking any feeling or sense of justice (idiom); cold and ruthless |
| 无所事事 | wúsuǒshìshì | to have nothing to do; to idle one's time away (idiom) |
| 无所作为 | wúsuǒzuòwéi | attempting nothing and accomplishing nothing (idiom); without any initiative or drive |
| 无微不至 | wúwēibùzhì | in every possible way (idiom); meticulous |
| 无忧无虑 | wúyōuwúlǜ | carefree and without worries (idiom) |
| 无足轻重 | wúzúqīngzhòng | insignificant |
| 五花八门 | wǔhuābāmén | myriad; all kinds of; all sorts of |
| 息息相关 | xīxīxiāngguān | closely bound up (idiom); intimately related |
| 熙熙攘攘 | xīxīrǎngrǎng | bustling with activity (idiom) |
| 喜出望外 | xǐchūwàngwài | to be pleased beyond one's expectations (idiom); overjoyed at the turn of events |
| 喜怒哀乐 | xǐnùāilè | four types of human emotions, namely: happiness, anger, sorrow and joy |
| 显而易见 | xiǎnéryìjiàn | clearly and easy to see (idiom); obviously; clearly; it goes without saying |
| 相比之下 | xiāngbǐzhīxià | by comparison |
| 相对而言 | xiāngduìéryán | relatively speaking; comparatively speaking |
| 相辅相成 | xiāngfǔxiāngchéng | to complement one another (idiom) |
| 相提并论 | xiāngtíbìnglùn | to discuss two disparate things together (idiom); to place on a par with |
| 相依为命 | xiāngyīwéimìng | mutually dependent for life (idiom); to rely upon one another for survival; interdependent |
| 想方设法 | xiǎngfāngshèfǎ | to think up every possible method (idiom); to devise ways and means |
| 小心翼翼 | xiǎoxīnyìyì | cautious and solemn (idiom); very carefully; prudent; gently and cautiously |
| 心安理得 | xīnānlǐdé | to have a clear conscience; to have no qualms about sth |
| 心急如焚 | xīnjírúfén | to burn with impatience; torn with anxiety |
| 心灵手巧 | xīnlíngshǒuqiǎo | capable; clever; dexterous |
| 心想事成 | xīnxiǎngshìchéng | to have one's wishes come true; wish you the best! |
| 欣欣向荣 | xīnxīnxiàngróng | (idiom) flourishing; thriving |
| 新陈代谢 | xīnchéndàixiè | metabolism (biology); the new replaces the old (idiom) |
| 形形色色 | xíngxíngsèsè | all kinds of; all sorts of; every (different) kind of |
| 形影不离 | xíngyǐngbùlí | inseparable (as form and shadow) |
| 兴高采烈 | xìnggāocǎiliè | happy and excited (idiom); in high spirits; in great delight |
| 胸有成竹 | xiōngyǒuchéngzhú | to plan in advance (idiom); forewarned is forearmed |
| 袖手旁观 | xiùshǒupángguān | to watch with folded arms (idiom); to look on without lifting a finger |
| 雪上加霜 | xuěshàngjiāshuāng | (idiom) to make matters even worse; to add insult to injury |
| 循序渐进 | xúnxùjiànjìn | in sequence, step by step (idiom); to make steady progress incrementally |
| 鸦雀无声 | yāquèwúshēng | lit. crow and peacock make no sound; absolute silence (idiom); absolute silence |
| 摇摇欲坠 | yáoyáoyùzhuì | tottering; on the verge of collapse |
| 夜以继日 | yèyǐjìrì | night and day (idiom); continuous strenuous effort |
| 衣食住行 | yīshízhùxíng | clothing, food, housing and transport (idiom); people's basic needs |
| 依依不舍 | yīyībùshě | reluctant to part (idiom); broken-hearted at having to leave |
| 一不小心 | yībùxiǎoxīn | to be a little bit careless; to have a moment of inattentiveness |
| 一动不动 | yīdòngbùdòng | motionless |
| 一概而论 | yīgàiérlùn | to lump different matters together (idiom) |
| 一技之长 | yījìzhīcháng | proficiency in a particular field (idiom); skill in a specialized area (idiom) |
| 一目了然 | yīmùliǎorán | obvious at a glance (idiom) |
| 一事无成 | yīshìwúchéng | to have achieved nothing |
| 怡然自得 | yíránzìdé | happy and content (idiom) |
| 以身作则 | yǐshēnzuòzé | to set an example (idiom); to serve as a model |
| 一长一短 | yīchángyīduǎn | talking endlessly; long-winded |
| 一成不变 | yīchéngbùbiàn | nothing much changes (idiom); always the same; stuck in a rut |
| 一筹莫展 | yīchóumòzhǎn | to be unable to find a solution; to be at wits' end |
| 一帆风顺 | yīfānfēngshùn | propitious wind throughout the journey (idiom); have a nice trip! |
| 一干二净 | yīgānèrjìng | thoroughly (idiom); completely; very clean |
| 一鼓作气 | yīgǔzuòqì | in a spurt of energy |
| 一举一动 | yījǔyīdòng | every movement; each and every move |
| 一毛不拔 | yīmáobùbá | stingy (idiom) |
| 一年到头 | yīniándàotóu | all year round |
| 一如既往 | yīrújìwǎng | just as in the past (idiom); as before; continuing as always |
| 一声不吭 | yīshēngbùkēng | to not say a word |
| 一塌糊涂 | yītāhútu | muddled and completely collapsing (idiom); in an awful condition |
| 一天到晚 | yītiāndàowǎn | all day long; the whole day |
| 一无所有 | yīwúsuǒyǒu | not having anything at all (idiom); utterly lacking; without two sticks to rub together |
| 一无所知 | yīwúsuǒzhī | not knowing anything at all (idiom); completely ignorant; without an inkling |
| 一心一意 | yīxīnyīyì | concentrating one's thoughts and efforts; single-minded; bent on; intently |
| 一言不发 | yīyánbùfā | to not say a word (idiom) |
| 一言一行 | yīyányīxíng | every word and action (idiom) |
| 一应俱全 | yīyīngjùquán | with everything needed available |
| 异口同声 | yìkǒutóngshēng | different mouths, same voice; to speak in unison (idiom) |
| 异想天开 | yìxiǎngtiānkāi | to indulge in fantasy |
| 抑扬顿挫 | yìyángdùncuò | cadence; modulation |
| 意料之外 | yìliàozhīwài | contrary to expectation; unexpected |
| 因人而异 | yīnrénéryì | varying from person to person (idiom); different for each individual |
| 引经据典 | yǐnjīngjùdiǎn | lit. to quote the classics; to quote chapter and verse (idiom) |
| 引人入胜 | yǐnrénrùshèng | to enchant; fascinating |
| 引人注目 | yǐnrénzhùmù | to attract attention; eye-catching |
| 应有尽有 | yīngyǒujìnyǒu | everything that should be here is here (idiom) |
| 勇往直前 | yǒngwǎngzhíqián | to advance bravely |
| 由此看来 | yóucǐkànlái | thereby; judging from this |
| 由此可见 | yóucǐkějiàn | from this, it can be seen that... |
| 犹豫不决 | yóuyùbùjué | hesitancy; indecision; to waver |
| 有的放矢 | yǒudìfàngshǐ | lit. to have a target in mind when shooting one's arrows (idiom); fig. to have a clear objective |
| 有口无心 | yǒukǒuwúxīn | to speak harshly but without any bad intent (idiom) |
| 有两下子 | yǒuliǎngxiàzi | to have real skill; to know one's stuff |
| 有声有色 | yǒushēngyǒusè | having sound and color (idiom); vivid; dazzling |
| 有所不同 | yǒusuǒbùtóng | to differ to some extent (idiom) |
| 有朝一日 | yǒuzhāoyīrì | one day; sometime in the future |
| 愚公移山 | yúgōngyíshān | the old man moves mountains (idiom); fig. where there's a will, there's a way |
| 与此同时 | yǔcǐtóngshí | at the same time; meanwhile |
| 与日俱增 | yǔrìjùzēng | to increase steadily; to grow with each passing day |
| 与时俱进 | yǔshíjùjìn | abreast of modern developments; to keep up with the times; progressive; timely |
| 与众不同 | yǔzhòngbùtóng | to stand out from the masses (idiom) |
| 愈演愈烈 | yùyǎnyùliè | ever more critical; problems get more and more intense |
| 原汁原味 | yuánzhīyuánwèi | original; authentic |
| 源源不断 | yuányuánbùduàn | a steady flow (idiom); an unending stream |
| 远近闻名 | yuǎnjìnwénmíng | to be known far and wide; to be well-known |
| 约定俗成 | yuēdìngsúchéng | established by popular usage (idiom); common usage agreement; customary convention |
| 杂乱无章 | záluànwúzhāng | disordered and in a mess (idiom); all mixed up and chaotic |
| 赞不绝口 | zànbùjuékǒu | to praise without cease (idiom); praise sb to high heaven |
| 赞叹不已 | zàntànbùyǐ | to be full of praise (idiom) |
| 斩草除根 | zhǎncǎochúgēn | to cut weeds and eliminate the roots (idiom); to eliminate completely |
| 张灯结彩 | zhāngdēngjiécǎi | to be decorated with lanterns and colored banners (idiom) |
| 朝气蓬勃 | zhāoqìpéngbó | full of youthful energy (idiom); vigorous; energetic; a bright spark |
| 朝三暮四 | zhāosānmùsì | lit. say three in the morning but four in the evening (idiom); to change sth that is already settled upon |
| 朝夕相处 | zhāoxīxiāngchǔ | to spend all one's time together (idiom) |
| 这样一来 | zhèyàngyīlái | thus; if this happens then |
| 针锋相对 | zhēnfēngxiāngduì | to oppose each other with equal harshness (idiom); tit for tat; measure for measure |
| 争分夺秒 | zhēngfēnduómiǎo | lit. fight minutes, snatch seconds (idiom); a race against time; making every second count |
| 争先恐后 | zhēngxiānkǒnghòu | striving to be first and fearing to be last (idiom); outdoing one another |
| 知识分子 | zhīshifènzǐ | intellectual; intelligentsia; learned person |
| 指手画脚 | zhǐshǒuhuàjiǎo | to gesticulate while talking (idiom); to criticize or give orders summarily |
| 至关重要 | zhìguānzhòngyào | extremely important; vital; crucial; essential |
| 众所周知 | zhòngsuǒzhōuzhī | as everyone knows (idiom) |
| 众志成城 | zhòngzhìchéngchéng | unity of will is an impregnable stronghold (idiom) |
| 重中之重 | zhòngzhōngzhīzhòng | of the utmost importance; of highest priority |
| 诸如此类 | zhūrúcǐlèi | things like this (idiom); and so on; and the rest; etc |
| 自力更生 | zìlìgēngshēng | regeneration through one's own effort (idiom); self-reliance |
| 自强不息 | zìqiángbùxī | to strive unremittingly; self-improvement |
| 自然而然 | zìránérrán | involuntary; automatically |
| 自始至终 | zìshǐzhìzhōng | from start to finish (idiom) |
| 自私自利 | zìsīzìlì | everything for self and selfish profit (idiom); with no regard for others |
| 自相矛盾 | zìxiāngmáodùn | to contradict oneself; self-contradictory; inconsistent |
| 自以为是 | zìyǐwéishì | to believe oneself infallible (idiom); to be opinionated |
| 自由自在 | zìyóuzìzài | free and easy (idiom); carefree; leisurely |
| 综上所述 | zōngshàngsuǒshù | to summarize; to sum up |
| 总的来说 | zǒngdeláishuō | generally speaking; to sum up; in summary; in short |
| 总而言之 | zǒngéryánzhī | in short; in a word; in brief |
| 纵横交错 | zònghéngjiāocuò | criss-crossed (idiom) |
| 走投无路 | zǒutóuwúlù | to be at an impasse (idiom); in a tight spot; at the end of one's rope; desperate |
| 足智多谋 | zúzhìduōmóu | resourceful; full of stratagems |
| 罪魁祸首 | zuìkuíhuòshǒu | criminal ringleader, main offender (idiom); main culprit; fig. main cause of a disaster |
| 左顾右盼 | zuǒgùyòupàn | glancing to left and right (idiom); to look all around |

I omitted these: 不好意思, 公共汽车, 电子邮件, 高速公路, 另一方面, 中华民族, 一般来说, 西班牙语, 意想不到, 这就是说, 阿拉伯语, 挨家挨户, 百科全书, 长期以来, 除此之外, 从今以后, 从早到晚, 帝国主义, 断断续续, 二氧化碳, 翻来覆去, 改革开放, 高尔夫球, 高新技术, 各式各样, 公共场所, 官僚主义, 和平共处, 截然不同, 人工智能, 社会主义, 十字路口, 市场经济, 讨价还价, 未成年人, 无家可归, 也就是说, 伊斯兰教, 资本主义.

Comment: I should note I only checked 4-character idioms (there are no words with 5+ characters), so this list omits some idioms like 穿小鞋 and 东道主.

Comment: Thanks for compiling! I saw your [post](https://www.chinese-forums.com/forums/topic/62524-details-on-the-hsk7-9-exam-are-out/?do=findComment&comment=489662) on Chinese Forums — am I right to believe that the [pdf](http://www.moe.gov.cn/jyb_xwfb/gzdt_gzdt/s5987/202103/W020210329527301787356.pdf) you linked there is the source of this list?

Comment: @laowai-guide: Yes, it should match the official standards (assuming I haven't made any mistakes [I'm not aware of any]).

Comment: Thanks for confirming! I've noticed that some of the words from that official document aren't showing up in some of my chengyu dictionaries, and I'm using authoritative sources like the 汉语大词典. Maybe some of the words are four characters but don't classify as 成语?

Comment: Figure I should include examples. I'm still going through the list, but 绝大多数 and 不怎么样 are at least two that aren't showing up as chengyu in the 汉语大词典's 成语词典, the 国家教育部研究院, or the 汉语成语小词典 (print book published by the 中国国际出版集团) 
(Had to delete and repost this — realized I'd mistyped some of the names)

Answer (score 2):

updated: I reviewed your list, I compared it with big idioms dictionray list, here is not idioms:

(1) 绝大多数_n

(2) 忽高忽低

(3) 说干就干 = 大丈夫做事，说干就干 (俗语)

(4) 说老实话 = 做老实人，说老实话，干老实事(格)

(5) 讨人喜欢_v

(6) 有所不同_v

(7) 知识分子_n

(8) 总的来说_c

So total idioms: 398

Comment: can you provide some context?

Comment: @ofou This just means those terms are normal vocabulary or expressions, they are not "idioms" (chengyu 成语) which are specific expressions issued from old Chinese literature or philosophical texts.